# Data isn't being passed from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to pass some variables from one VC to the other, the variables in the VC i'm passing to, doesn't get updated. Here is how I've done it so far:

VC 1

```
var note: String = ""
var reward: Int = 0
var deadline: Int = 0
```

VC 2

```
var vcOne = VcOne()
var note: String = "Some note..."
var reward: Int = 100
var deadline: Int = 988934
```

In the function where I pop VC 2, I pass the data from that one to update VC 1 like this:

```
func passData()
{
    vcOne.note = self.note
    vcOne.reward = self.reward
    vcOne.deadline = self.deadline

    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

But when I print the values in VC 1 after I have passed, they are still empty or 0.

I have used this method to pass data before, but this time it doesn't seem to work. Should I be doing it differently? What's the best way to pass data like the way I showed?

EDIT: Here is my real code

VC 1:

```
class CreateMissionController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate
{
    var deadline: Int = 0
    var missionLatitude: Double = 0
    var missionLongitude: Double = 0


func handleSetLocation()
{
    let createMapController = CreateMapController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(createMapController,animated: true)
}
```

VC 2

```
class CreateMapController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,     MKMapViewDelegate
{
    var createMissionController: CreateMissionController?
    var missionLatitude: Double?
    var missionLongitude: Double?
    var deadline: Int?


func handleChooseLocation()
{
    missionLatitude = missionLocation!.latitude
    missionLongitude = missionLocation!.longitude

    createMissionController?.missionLatitude = missionLatitude!
    createMissionController?.missionLongitude = missionLongitude!

    let timeInterval = deadlineDate?.timeIntervalSince1970
    let deadlineInt = Int(timeInterval!)

    createMissionController?.deadline = deadlineInt

    print(missionLatitude!)
    print(missionLongitude!)
    print(deadlineInt)

    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

when I print in VC 2, they display the correct values, but if I try to print in VC 1 after I have executed the function in VC 2, they just print the default values.

Comment: when do you try to print data of VC1 exaclty ? between the assignation and the pop view ? or after the pop ? 
can you show us how you try to print them ?

Comment: After I execute the the passData function. Basically VC 1 pushes VC 2 to gather some data, which I am trying to send back to VC 1.

Comment: in your example you redefinning a new VC1 into VC2. so you're assigning value to this new one. 
if you want the data back, pass VC1 to VC2, assign to VC1 into VC2 and then, you"ll find your data back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC1

```
var note: String = ""
var reward: Int = 0
var deadline: Int = 0

var vc2 = VcTwo()
vc2.vcOne = self
```

VC 2

```
var vcOne : VcOne
var note: String = "Some note..."
var reward: Int = 100
var deadline: Int = 988934

func passData()
{
    vcOne.note = self.note
    vcOne.reward = self.reward
    vcOne.deadline = self.deadline

    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

As mentionned in my commentary, you're reassigning a new vcOne, so you set another object and don't get the data back.
by assigning `vc2.vcOne` to self, you're telling vc2 to use your current object

Comment: Thank you! Such a small error on my side, but caused me many hours of frustration...

Comment: I'm glad it helped you 
no more hours of frustration now :)

Answer (score 1):

In VC2 you create a new VC1 with `var vcOne = VcOne()`. When passign your data, you are probably passing it to the wrong instance.

You should define the property as:

```
var vcOne: VC1
```

and pass the existing instance instead

**Update**

You have to set a reference to the mission VC:

```
func handleSetLocation()
{
    let createMapController = CreateMapController()
    createMapController.createMissionController = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(createMapController,animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and I'm sure you are right, but it still doesn't work... I will edit my question with more details